# Appending one ResumableSource to another

Tags: haskell, conduit

How do you append one `ResumableSource` to another one when they are not explicitly an instance of `Monad` ? Here is a toy example below - `a` has `Monad` constraint while `b` doesn't have it. So we can append `a's` but not `b's`:

```
Prelude>  import Data.Conduit
Prelude Data.Conduit> import Data.ByteString as BS
Prelude Data.Conduit BS> import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
Prelude Data.Conduit BS Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> let a = newResumableSource (yield (BS.pack [5])) -- this one has monad constraint
Prelude Data.Conduit BS Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> :t a
a :: Monad m => ResumableSource m ByteString
Prelude Data.Conduit BS Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> :t a >> a
a >> a
  :: (Monad m, Monad (ResumableSource m)) =>
     ResumableSource m ByteString
Prelude Data.Conduit BS Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> let b = undefined :: ResumableSource (ResourceT IO) ByteString
Prelude Data.Conduit BS Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> :t b >> b

<interactive>:1:3:
    No instance for (Monad (ResumableSource (ResourceT IO)))
      arising from a use of ‘>>’
    In the expression: b >> b
```

The reason I am asking it because I have an `HTTP ResumableSource` with same type as `b` above, to which I will like to prepend the content-length, before feeding it to sink. Currently, it looks like this:

```
responseBody rsp  $$+- sink
```

Which I will like to change to something like this:

```
((newResumableSource (yield content-len)) >> (responseBody rsp))  $$+- sink
```

Comment: Note carefully the inferred type of `a >> a :: (Monad m, Monad (ResumableSource m)) => ResumableSource m ByteString`. When you instantiate `m`, the elaborator will search for an instance of `Monad (ResumableSource m)`. Since `ResumableSource` has no `Monad` instance, type checking will fail. In other words, there's no way to _use_ `a >> a`.

Comment: ha, yep, good point. Wonder if I could just do a yield to sink without the sink terminating after the first source is done? Like `yield content-len $$ sink; (responseBody rsp))  $$+- sink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to prepend initial message to `ResumableSource` seems to be to use a `conduit` which yields that initial message and then becomes a pass-through. Here, I have borrowed the code from [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.6/docs/src/Data-Conduit-List.html#map) conduit to create such a conduit:

```
passThruWInit :: Monad m => BS.ByteString -> C.Conduit BS.ByteString m BS.ByteString
passThruWInit initMsg = do
  C.yield initMsg -- generate initial message first
  C.awaitForever $ C.yield -- now pass-through conduit for all messages
```

Now, we update `responseBody rsp  $$+- sink` code to fit it in between:

```
responseBody rsp $=+ passThruWInit someInitMsg $$+- sink
```

The net result is that `someInitMsg` is yielded first, and then `responseBody` content is streamed through. That way, we can prepend content-length and other metadata to the resumable HTTP response body.